# How hide a drop-down list when the model is empty in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, resources

I need to hide a drop-down list when the model is empty and to show it when there are values in the model.

1. I have a service to get the values.

   ```
   angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource'])
       .factory('OptionsSelect', ['$resource',
           function ($resource) {
               return $resource('http://myapi/miapp/optionselect/1', {}, {
                   query: {
                       method: 'GET',
                       params: { id: '1' },
                       isArray: false
                   }
               });
           }
       ])
   ```
2. The possible result is:

   ```
   {"1":"red","5":"blue","34":"blue"}
   ```

or

```
<pre>
{}
</pre>
```

1. In the controller:

   ```
   $scope.optionsSelect = OptionsSelect.query();
   ```
2. The view is:

   ```
    <div class="form-group" ng-hide="isHide()">
       <select class="form-control" ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in optionsSelect">
    </div>
   ```

   You can view the code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/finsi/LMJXC/38/

Comment: Your query indicates that it is expecting an array (`isArray: true`), but your result is not an array, it's just an object.  That's going to cause an error.

Comment: You are right but is a typo, in my real code I have "isArray: false" and doesn't work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've created **[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tazewe/2/edit)** for you please have a look. You should add model to you select directive and use $promise like it is below. I hope that will help.

HTML:

```
 <div class="form-group" ng-show="optionsSelect">
    <select class="form-control" 
            ng-model="option.color"
            ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in optionsSelect">
 </div>
```

JS:

```
  app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, OptionsSelect){
    $scope.optionsSelect = {};

  OptionsSelect.query().$promise.then(function(optionSelectCollection){

    angular.copy(optionSelectCollection, $scope.optionsSelect);
  });




});
```

Comment: Sorry, but don't work.
If I define the model inside of the controller is ok. But when I get the data from OptionsSelect.query() not.

Comment: You can try with optionSelect.length >0. What is not working I'd always shown or always hide?

Comment: ng-show="optionsSelect.length>0" does not work either

Comment: I this case "optionSelect.length >0" always hide.

Comment: Are you sure that resources return any data?

Comment: Yes, I sure. I send you a screenshot: http://www.preproduccion.es/angular-demos/drop-down-list/error/img1.png.

Comment: This is a screenshot of console.log(OptionsSelect); http://www.preproduccion.es/angular-demos/drop-down-list/error/img2.png

Comment: So everything is fine as your object optionSelect is empty your dropdown will be hidden

Comment: Yes, I know,  that's why I asked in the forum. Everything  seems to be fine, but doesn't work. Thank you your time. I will continue investigating

Comment: Thanks. I've created jsfiddle with your code and doesn't work when the value is empty. http://jsfiddle.net/finsi/LMJXC/38/

Comment: please see http://jsfiddle.net/LMJXC/41/. Angular by default adding keys ($promise,$resolved,$get,$save,$query,$remove,$delete) to each $resource object s for my the only way is check if $resource object has any other properties then default if not we can assume that it is empty. You can change in line 9 OptionsSelect to OptionsSelect2 and everything is working.

Comment: Yes!  That's the solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, when I vote,  I see appear a message "Vote up requires 15 reputation"http://www.preproduccion.es/angular-demos/drop-down-list/error/vote.png I haven't reputation too much. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So these selected optionsSelect objects are undefined, they stay undefined if nothing is returned and become objects if something *is* returned. Can you just hide them if they're undefined? Such as in this fiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/LMJXC/40/

```
<div class="form-group" ng-hide="optionsSelect === undefined">
```

and

```
<div class="form-group" ng-hide="optionsSelect2 === undefined">
```

Comment: Thanks you. Your solution  is fine. But in my code, I haven't an undefined results, I have this:  http://www.preproduccion.es/angular-demos/drop-down-list/error/img2.png. The solution is http://jsfiddle.net/LMJXC/41/ from sylwester